# Cakephp2.0 is removing extra spaces from data received from mysql

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have information saved in mysql database

Input given

```
$name = 'This is the sample                      data'
```

Actually getting output which is not required

```
 $name = 'This is the sample data'
```

Desired Output

```
$name = 'This is the sample                      data'
```

while retrieving from database I can see using `PR()` which is also fine
but while `echo $name` it removes extra spaces which is not required.

Comment: How are you debugging. If in browser the HTML rendering is going to remove most of the white space. You need to `var_dump` it or use logging to check the literal string value.

Comment: anyway I have to show this information on browser only, so I need those extra spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers collapse white space in html. That means two or more spaces are always collapsed to one. If you really need to display the text as is, use the `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre>This is the sample                      data</pre>
```

This tells your browser that the text is preformatted.